# Add new lines just before curly braces at a specific block using sed

Tags: regex, sed

My python code looks like this:

```
def one():
    #lines of code
    context = {
        #lines of code
    }

def two():
    #lines of code
    context = {
        #lines of code
    }
    context.up({ #lines 
    })
```

I want to add "Some new line" in context part of function two just before the closing curly braces like this:

```
def one():
    #lines of code
    context = {
        #lines of code
    }

def two():
    #lines of code
    context = {
        #lines of code
        Some new line
    }
    context.up({ #lines 
    })
```

How to do this using sed?

I tried following command:

`sed -i '/^def two.*context={/,/^[[:space:]]}/{s/^\([[:space:]]*\)}/\1some new line\n&/;}' file`

but it does not seem to make any change.

Comment: Do you want python or sed?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about Python at all.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want this change using sed.

Comment: @python_user Asking SO to write code for you from scratch is generally frowned upon.  Show us what sed code you tried so far and what problem you are having with it.

Comment: @John1024 I tried with this command `sed -i '/^def two.*context={/,/^[[:space:]]}/{s/^\([[:space:]]*\)}/\1some new line\n&/;}' file`  but it made no changes to the code.

Comment: Why there are negative votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/def two/,/^\s*context\>/!b;/^\s*context\>/!b;:a;n;/^\s*}/!ba;i some new line' file
```

Limit the scope to `def two` and within `context` read lines upto the closing `}` and insert a new line.

The first sed instruction is a regexp range i.e. if the lines are not between `def two` and `context` print them as usual but do not process them further with any sed instructions (`b` means break out of any further commands). Likewise the next regexp ignores any lines except that containing `context`. From this address print the current line in the pattern space (PS) and populate the PS with the next line (`n`). If that line does not contain the `}` jump back (`ba`) to the position `:a`. Otherwise insert (`i`) some new text and then print the contents of the PS.

To retain indentation use:

```
sed '/def two/,/^\s*context\b/!b;/^\s*context\b/!b;:a;n;/^\s*}/!h;//!ba;x;s/\S\+.*/some new line with indent/p;g' file
```

Comment: This is not working because I have curly braces inside code also. So this new line is getting added before the first occurrence of the curly braces but I want it inside the context.

Comment: This expression fails when there is one more closing curly braces after the closing curly braces of context. It new lines get added to the last one. I have edited the question. Please see. Do we need to include "=" symbol in expression now?

Comment: I made some changes and I am getting desired output. `sed '/def two/,/^\s*context\x20/!b;/^\s*context\x20/!b;:a;n;/^\s*}/!ba;i some new line' file` I just added a space after context and it worked. Is this the correct way? @potong

Comment: @python_user yes or use `\s` or `\b` or `\>` to represent the end of the word. However bear in mind (not in this case) a word may be the last thing in a line so may not be followed by a space (use `\b` or `\>` is more bullet-proof).

Comment: Today this sed command is not working. From all these it was perfectly fine. But when I ran this sed command today, suddenly it did not make any change in the file. Can you help me out? There were no errors displayed but it did not work.

Comment: @python_user you need to narrow down where you expect the changes to occur and compare them to earlier times when it did, then you can apply debugging tools i.e. `p` or `l` commands to see what has changed. Good Luck